# Preventing relationship data leak exploit with graphql

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, prisma

How do you prevent people from querying for relationships of objects they should not see in graphql?

For instance, assume we have the following datamodel.

```
type Board {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    boardUserRoles: [BoardUserRole!]!
}

type BoardUserRole {
    id: ID! @unique
    board: Board!
    user: User!
    role: BoardRole!
}

type User {
    id: ID! @unique
    tasks: [Task!]!
    userName: String! @unique
    boardUserRoles: [BoardUserRole!]!
}
```

This is a setup where there are users who have access to certain boards. And the `BoardUserRole` determines what role a user has for a specific table.

Now, i come along and query for a board that i have permission to and take a look at its name.

```
query {
    board(where: {id: "3"}) {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

That is perfectly fine. However, i can get to the other users of the system and see the tasks they have if i change the query. I can basically see anything related to that user.

```
query {
    board(where: {id: "3"}) {
        id
        name
        boardUserRoles {
            user {
                tasks
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you protect against this type of query?

Comment: this is serious question? it's like 'I have a sql table with password - how to not show them with select' - API simply shouldn't return data you don't have permissions. It doesn't matter it's sql, rest, graphql, whatever. Check prisma docs?

Comment: @xadm yes. Serious. Maybe I am not understanding something correctly, but if a user has access to board 3, how would you prevent them from using the rest of the schema to traverse the graph to get to other data? You make it sound obvious, so please let me know what you are thinking. I have read through prisma, Apollo, and graphql and found nothing on how to restrict someone from asking for the entire graph back in one query. I know of a way to do it by overriding the `info`, that comes on a resolver, with only the data I want them to get, but I don't want to take that ability away from users.

Comment: In graphql you can have field level security. `It doesn't matter it's traversing or simple query` - resolver always take it separately. You should restrict returning fields when user doesn't have permission. F.e. don't show some data, don't update post content when you aren't author or moderatot... 
2 sec googling: https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/1768  , prisma permission directives ...

Comment: @xadm those are really good reads, I believe that is exactly what I am looking for. Will look more into this on Monday. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @xadm. I was able to put together a solution that worked perfectly for me.

After reading this article about how [query execution works](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-the-schema-ac5e2950214e/). I figured out how to write field resolvers. The field resolver allows me to determine how exactly a specific field is resolved. I made a field resolver for `Board: boardUserRoles`.

Here is my field resolver.

```
Board: {
    boardUserRoles: async (parent: Board, args, ctx, info) => {
        // getting user id from header.
        const userId: string = VerificationHelper.getUserId(ctx);

        // Verifying role of user.
        return VerificationHelper.verifyRole(userId, ["ADMIN"], ctx).pipe(
            map(
                (result: boolean) => {
                    // If the user has an admin role, show the roles
                    if (result) {
                        return parent.boardUserRoles;
                    // If not, map the results to undefined
                    } else {
                        return undefined;
                    }
                }
            )
        ).toPromise();
    }
}
```

I then added that resolver to my resolver list in the graphql creation.

```
const server: GraphQLServer = new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: "src/schema.graphql",
    resolvers: {
        Query: QueryResolvers,
        Mutation: MutationResolvers,
        Subscription: SubscriptionResolvers,
        ...FieldResolvers, // A file that contains all my field resolvers.
        AuthPayload
    },
    context: (req: any) => ({
        ...req,
        prisma: new Prisma({
            typeDefs: "src/generated/prisma.graphql",
            endpoint: endpoint()
        })
    })
});
```

This is a very basic field resolver. It checks the users role and determines if it should hide the data or show the data. I went through my entire schema and found other data exploits. I corrected the ones i found with field resolvers and everything is working great now.

Thanks for the help @xadm, your references pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: That's great!  Let me know if you have any other questions around Prisma.

Comment: @nburk Will do, learning graphql right now and really enjoying it. Preferring it right now over a normal restAPI.

Answer (score 0):

When using Prisma, you can modify the data structures that are exposed to your client applications by redefining the type in the **application schema**.

The SDL definitions you're showing in your question look like the **Prisma data model** to me. I assume you also have an API server (possibly implemented with `graphl-yoga` or `apollo-server`) that exposes the GraphQL API which is going to be consumed by your client applications. Let's call the GraphQL schema defining this API the **application schema**. Inside the application schema you can *redefine* the types from your data model in the way you want to expose them to your clients.

Here's a simple example:

Assume you have the following `User` type in your Prisma data model:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

Now, you don't want to expose the `password` to your clients. So what you can do is redefine the `User` type in the way that your clients should be able to access it. Here is how you can define it in the application schema (often called `schema.graphql`):

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

You can find a running version of this example [here](https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/node-graphql-server/tree/master/advanced). Also, if you're confused by the terminology of the application schema and data model, I recommend to you reading [this](https://docs-beta.prisma.io/1.13/understand-prisma/building-graphql-servers-with-prisma-dvw4/#a-layered-architecture-for-your-graphql-server:-two-graphql-apis) part of the Prisma docs.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. I did not know that i could redefine my types in the `schema.graphql`. I thought that was intended for just resolvers. That is insightful, but not the solution i need for my problem. I need certain things exposed based on authorization. I figured it out and will post my solution in a few minutes. Thank you!